# tr on mac: misplaced sequence asterisk

Tags: tr

I'm very new to all of this so please excuse any mistakes.
I'm working on on a mac.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [here](http://www.polarmicrobes.org/phylogenetic-placement-re-re-visited/#comment-381)
When I type in `tr "[ -%,;\(\):=\.\\\*[]\"\']" "_" < hug_tol.fasta > hug_tol.clean.fasta`
I get the error message `tr:misplaced sequence asterisk`
I'm guessing that something in the file must be wrong, but since I'm trying to remove those characters the error message doesn't make sense.
I haven't found anything on Google so maybe someone can help me.

Comment: a minimal example of the file that reproduces the problem would be helpful

Comment: @Nick. I'm pretty sure it's not the file.

Comment: this is the [download link](http://www.nature.com/article-assets/npg/nmicrobiol/2016/nmicrobiol201648/extref/nmicrobiol201648-s7.txt) to the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the tutorial appears to be using quasi-regex character class syntax for `tr`. `tr` is much more limited in it's scope than that. It only accepts a few escape characters and special characters. Simplify your command to

```
tr "%,;():=.*[]\"\' \\\\\-" "_" < hug_tol.fasta > hug_tol.clean.fasta
```

The `-` character does have special meaning, so put it at the end: in the beginning it will be interpreted as a command-line argument, while in the middle it specifies a character range. In bash, `*` won't be expanded in double quotes. For `tr`, to specify a plain `\`, you need a double `\` (since it's the escape character). To get that through bash, you need `\\\\`.

You may also want to consider using the `-c` option to specify the complement set (the characters you want to keep), since it is probably much smaller:

```
tr -c "A-Za-z0-9_" "_" < hug_tol.fasta > hug_tol.clean.fasta
```

or more tersely

```
tr -c "[:alnum:]" "_" < hug_tol.fasta > hug_tol.clean.fasta
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I gave this a try and it resulted in:  
`tr: illegal option -- %       
usage: tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2       
       tr [-Ccu] -d string1       
       tr [-Ccu] -s string1      
       tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2`

Comment: @CyrC. I've added a bit more. You may just want to use `-c [:alnum:]` instead of that complicated string

Comment: good call, I didn't know about the -c command before. Thank you!